# matching two fields in a form from two functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two fields that I'd like to match. (already done the validation functions for field 1 and 2)

field01 has a client number Txxxxx xxxxx (can be T G or M)

field02 has the area code 416 / 905 / 647

I'd like to match T with 416, G with 905, and M with 647.
and show a relationship error if the rules were broken.

I made a separate function trying to compare the two.

```
     function validatecompare(errMessages)
   {

       var clientID = document.pizza.field02;
       var telenum = document.pizza.field03;

       var client = clientID.value;
       var phone  = telenum.value;
       var firstL = "";
       var areaC  = "";


firstL=client.substr(0,1);
areaC =phone.substr(0,3);


     if ((firstL) !=areaC)
       {
          errMessages += "<li>Client Number and Telephone No. are not consistent with our set up rules.</li>\n";
       }


     return errMessages;

 }
```

I know that's wrong, I just have no idea how to compare two fields from two separate functions. The error message will pop up regardless of what I do. Even if I violate the rules for field 1 and 2 the error message will pop up with those when it shouldn't.

If there is somewhere I can read up on how to do this would be excellent for future reference.

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `firstL` have always one char, `areaC` always three, they'll never be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're literally comparing `416` and `T`. You need some kind of lookup table:

```
function validatecompare(errMessages) {
    var clientID = document.pizza.field02;
    var telenum  = document.pizza.field03;

    var client = clientID.value;
    var phone  = telenum.value;
    var firstL = client.charAt(0);
    var areaC  = phone.substr(0, 3);

    var areaCodes = {
        '416': 'T',
        '905': 'G',
        '647': 'M'
    };

    if(firstL !== areaCodes[areaC]) {
        errMessages += "<li>Client Number and Telephone No. are not consistent with our set up rules.</li>\n";
    }

    return errMessages;
}
```

Comment: so by doing '416' : 'T'  inside that variable, that does a match up?. and you used charAt because...char is for letters right? and charAt(0) would find the letter at index zero? Sorry if what I'm asking is stupid lol, I just want to make sure I understand what's happening here.

Comment: @Umeed: Yup, exactly. What it does is create an object with those properties, and you look up the property in the object. `.charAt(0)` is the first character - it's just a more concise way of saying `.substr(0, 1)`.